# sqlplus select statement inside case

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm working with SQLPLUS and really need to be able to use an `IF/THEN/ELSE`, but I haven't been able to locate any information on how I can get that to work. (Sources all say it can't be done), so I'm trying to use `CASE` to do the same thing. I need to look at the sysdate and if it is between date A and date B then run Select statement. If it is not goto the next `CASE` statement. Here's a snippit of what I'm trying to do:

```
CASE  
    WHEN sysdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('28/08/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('20/11/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      THEN
         (SELECT 
          schools.abbreviation,
          students.entrydate,
          students.lastfirst as Student,
          students.student_number,
          students.grade_level,
          courses.course_name,
          teachers.lastfirst as Teacher,
          pgfinalgrades.grade,
          round(pgfinalgrades.percent) as Percent,
            (CASE
                WHEN ps_customfields.getcf('Students', students.ID, 'zz_B_Soccer') = '1'
                THEN 'Boys_Soccer'
            ELSE NULL 
          END) AS "Athletic Sport - Fall"
FROM pgfinalgrades
    JOIN sections on pgfinalgrades.sectionid = sections.id
    JOIN courses on upper(sections.course_number) = upper(courses.course_number)
    JOIN cc on pgfinalgrades.studentid = cc.studentid and sections.id = cc.sectionid and sysdate between cc.dateenrolled and cc.dateleft
    JOIN students on pgfinalgrades.studentid = students.id
    JOIN prefs on prefs.name = 'curfgname-S' || sections.schoolid and pgfinalgrades.finalgradename = to_char(substr(prefs.value, 1,2))
    JOIN terms on terms.schoolid = sections.schoolid and sysdate between terms.firstday and terms.lastday and terms.isyearrec = 1
    JOIN schools on sections.schoolid = schools.school_number
    JOIN teachers on sections.teacher = teachers.id
WHERE students.enroll_status = 0
  AND sysdate between cc.dateenrolled and cc.dateleft
  AND (pgfinalgrades.grade = 'C-'
    OR pgfinalgrades.grade = 'D'
    OR pgfinalgrades.grade = 'D-'
    OR pgfinalgrades.grade = 'E'
    OR pgfinalgrades.grade = 'F'
    )
  AND --Fall Sports
    (       ps_customfields.getcf('Students', students.ID, 'zz_B_Soccer') IS NOT NULL
         OR ps_customfields.getcf('Students', students.ID, 'zz_B_Cross_Country') IS NOT NULL
         OR ps_customfields.getcf('Students', students.ID, 'zz_Golf') IS NOT NULL  
    ));
```

Next would be Winter Sports, then Spring sports. 
I get the error "unknown command" on the sysdate line, then it runs each case. I'm not sure how to get it to grab today's date, determine which case it falls under, then run that one for me to output. I intend to automate this to run weekly during the whole school year and don't want to have to touch it more than once per year. 
If anyone can think of a better way to do this, I'm all ears. :)

Comment: It's not that clear to me what you need to do. Try to build a simple example ( a sample table with a few meaningful  data) to explain what you need to do. You may also want to have a look at [mcve]

Comment: No, `CASE` is not a flow control construct, mainly because SQL is a query language rather than a programming language. You can certainly use PL/SQL but, well, I wouldn't write an entire application in PL/SQL anyway. Said that, I suspect you can get your results with standard SQL but of course we know nothing about your problem.

Comment: Also note that you can't select a different number of columns for each CASE stmt.  Rather, you need use subquery selects that return either a  scalar (or an object type), e.g: select case when dummy = 'X' then (select count(*) from all_users) else (select count(*) from dual) end cnt from dual; OR select case when dummy = 'X' then (select myType(user_id,created) from all_users where rownum=1) else (select myType(111,sysdate) from dual) end from dual;

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working with SQLPLUS and really need to be able to use an
>   IF/THEN/ELSE, but I haven't been able to locate any information on how
>   I can get that to work. (`Sources all say it can't be done`)

I would say this can be very well done in PLSQL anonymous block and we can use `IF/ELSE` statement. 
Please see a breif demo:

```
begin
   if sysdate between to_date ('28/08/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                  and to_date ('20/11/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
   then
      dbms_output.put_line ('Sysdate is beteeween the date range');
   ---You can run your sql query here
   else
      dbms_output.put_line ('Not in date range');
   ---You can run your sql query here

   end if;
end;
```

Output

```
Not in date range

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```